# Rails: CSS is not loading in app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I tried imputing this code in  `app/assets/stylesheets` in `application.css.scss` file but... why isn't it working?? What am I doing wrong?

```
<style>
 body {
   background: #4778aa;
 }

 .review_title {
   margin: 0 0 20px 0;
 }
 .reviews {
   padding: 15px 0;
   bording-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
   .star-rating {
     padding-bottom: 8px;
   }
 }
</style>
```

with no lock

EDIT:

I've also tried removing the style tag with no luck:

```
 body {
   background: #4778aa;
 }

 .review_title {
   margin: 0 0 20px 0;
 }
 .reviews {
   padding: 15px 0;
   bording-bottom: 1px solid #EAEAEA;
   .star-rating {
     padding-bottom: 8px;
   }
 }
```

Comment: u can't use style tag(or any html) inside css/scss.

Comment: I tried removing the the style tag at first and only resorted to it after it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put an `application.css` file into your `app/assets/stylesheets` in which you

```
*= require_tree ./<css_dir>
```

your `scss` files, like this all your `.scss` will end up in the `application.css` that you can refer in your `<head>`.